# About Edge of Tomorrow: How Rita can know she lost her powers?

Tags: edge-of-tomorrow

In the film Edge of Tomorrow Rita Vrataski knows she had lost her powers (coming back after her death) due to a blood trasfusion, but how she can know that? she should die first right?